# Return statement error, return null instead

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a method to display an error message if the user enters a number other than 1 - 4, but I'm getting a *missing return statement* error.

```
public int CheckAnswers () {
    boolean incorrectAnswer = true;

    do {
        playerAnswer = CheckAnswers();
         if (playerAnswer < 1 || playerAnswer > 4) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect number.");
            System.out.println("Please enter a  number between 1 and 4");
         } else {
               return (playerAnswer); }

        } while (incorrectAnswer);

   }
```

The error points to the last bracket. I've done some looking around online and I think the problem is that I don't have a return statement in both parts of the *if-else statement*. But if they have entered an incorrect number I don't want to return anything. I tried using the below code unsuccessfully.

```
public int CheckAnswers () {
    boolean incorrectAnswer = true;

    do {
        playerAnswer = CheckAnswers();
         if (playerAnswer < 1 || playerAnswer > 4) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect number.");
            System.out.println("Please enter a  number between 1 and 4");
              return (null);
         } else {
               return (playerAnswer); }

        } while (incorrectAnswer);

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a return statement of return -1 right after the do while.
You will not ever reach that code, but it will make the compiler happy who is not able to understand the logic of your code and just sees that there are possible execution paths that don't return anything.

```
public int CheckAnswers () {
    boolean incorrectAnswer = true;

    do {
        playerAnswer = CheckAnswers();
        if (playerAnswer < 1 || playerAnswer > 4) {
          System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect number.");
          System.out.println("Please enter a  number between 1 and 4");
        } 
        else {
           return (playerAnswer); 
        }
    } while (incorrectAnswer);
    return -1; //unreachable statement
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler's analysis does not determine that

```
do {
    playerAnswer = CheckAnswers();
     if (playerAnswer < 1 || playerAnswer > 4) {
        System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect number.");
        System.out.println("Please enter a  number between 1 and 4");
     } else {
           return (playerAnswer); }

    } while (incorrectAnswer);
```

is indeed an infinite loop, and the only way to get out of the loop is the `return` in the `else` branch. (Since `incorrectAnswer` cannot be changed except by cosmic rays flipping bits, it is, but the compiler isn't convinced.)

Thus it wants a `return` in case the loop is left in a different way.

If you make the loop condition a literal `true`,

```
do {
    // code
} while(true);
```

the compiler will know that the loop can only be left via the `return` in the `else` branch (you can and should eliminate the `boolean incorrectAnswer;` then).

As [yannis hristofakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839554/yannis-hristofakis) [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17126589/1011995), calling `playerAnswer = CheckAnswers();` immediately in the loop causes an infinite recursion, and that will lead to a stack overflow. You need to call a method that obtains some input from the user instead there.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm amazed that 3 answers were posted and none of them mentioned that*

1. It's an eternal procedure since you call recursevly the `CheckAnswers` method.
2. You can't return  `null` for primitive return type methods.

I think you should skip the parenthesis.

`return playerAnswer;`

Comment: Point 1 (good observation, by the way) has nothing to do with the compilation error. It will lead to a stack overflow when the thing compiles and is run, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public int CheckAnswers () {
    boolean incorrectAnswer = true;

    do {
       playerAnswer = CheckAnswers();
       if (playerAnswer < 1 || playerAnswer > 4) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect number.");
            System.out.println("Please enter a  number between 1 and 4");
       } else {
            incorrectAnswer = false;
       }
    } while (incorrectAnswer);

    return playerAnswer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered! The problem is solved! :)